# MVC4 Jquery Popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm hoping to get some advice on how best to achieve the following in .NET MVC 4.

I have a View with a list of Companies on it, a simple for each through an Enumeration building up a html table. each row has a button or link, when pressed the button / link opens a pop-up window. Inside the pop-up window would be a partial view, containing a form to add a new user which posts to its own method on another controller.

what I would like to happen is the form to be self contained within the pop-up and not affect the main window until I close the pop-up and then refresh the parent window, but still be able to submit the new user and get that persisted within the pop-up.

can any one offer any advice.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think posting the form within the dialog using AJAX could be a good solution.

You could take benefits of serialize data of the form values with the next javascript in jquery:

```
$("#submit-button").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var form = $("#dialog-form");
    var form_collection = form.serialize();
    $.post("/Controller/Action/", form_collection, function (data) {
        if (data) {
            $("#dialog").close();
        } else {
            alert("Something go wrong!");
        }
    });
});
```

And in the Controller:

```
[Authorize]
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public JsonResult Action(FormCollection form)
{
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.Name = form["Name"];
    newUser.Company = form["Company"];
    newUser.Address = form["Address"];

    dataBaseService.SaveOrUpdate(newUser);

    return Json(new { response = true, userSaved = newUser }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I hope I understand your question right!